# How to check if the user have logout from Google/Facebook/GitHub etc - OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, token

I just finished my first OAuth2.0 project! Simple login with Facebook.
When I want to access, then I will become navigated to Facebook login page. I login and then I will be transfered back again. Great!

Now I want to tell Spring Boot that Spring Security need to check every user. 
Because if logout from Facebook, then I can still access the page anyway. It's like the secret key is still there that allowing me to pass.

I want Spring Security to do a quick check "Right user? Have you logout?".

Is that possible?

I have my security configuration here:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/Intranet/Bokning").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**", "/Intranet**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible or at least I don't know a way how platforms like Facebook/Google/GitHub share the login status of a user on their platform.

You usually use these providers to authenticate a user and then set a cookie (`JSESSIONID` by default) which is a token for authentication details for your Spring application and not bound to the session you might have on the platform you used to login with.

There is a great [Spring Boot Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) that explains how the Social Login works with OAuth2

Comment: Okej. I take that as an answer.